# Image Processing with MMX in Linux

Tags: c, image-processing, mmx

I want to use the MMX instruction set to optimize my Linux C program, which does lots of operations on images stored in RGB format (each RGB component is stored in an unsigned char).  The operations are trivial: I subtract one image from the other pixel by pixel, and accumulate the sum of the absolute values of the differences.  (basically, I have a small image, or pattern, and I'm trying to find if that pattern exists in a larger image).

I know this can be coded in assembly language using the MMX instructions to do the individual byte operations in SIMD fashion.  However, is there an easier way?  Maybe a library, or a higher-level interface that uses the MMX instructions?

Comment: Have you seen this project?  [libjpeg-turbo](http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/)

Comment: Well, thanks for your help, but I don't think that has anything to do with my question.  :)

Comment: Actually, this page is a good concise description and example of how to incorporate MMX instructions into a GNU C code: http://vast.uccs.edu/~tboult/frame/Boult/linux-mmx.html

Comment: Try the Intel IPP libs, they have linux versions, and internally use the SIMD instructions.  Unfortunately it's a payware SDK (free redistribs), but you can install and use it for awhile without buying anything.

Comment: Aren't the Intel C compilers free for non-commercial use?

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is a header you `#include`, usually called something like `intrinsics.h`. [This page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4505/Introduction-to-MMX-Programming) shows how to use MMX with C. It `#includes` the file `emmintrin.h`. Maybe that file exists in Linux?

Also, if you're working on hardware that's remotely recent, you probably want to use at least SSE, if not SSE2. I believe they can be included in a similar way.

Comment: Yes, I have a very recent CPU.  Should I use SSE2 instead of the MMX instructions?  This might be a lot easier because I use instructions like _mm_add_pi8() directly from C.  Is that equivalent to coding MMX instructions in assembly language?